# How do I aquire touch coordinates for touches outside and inside my app?

Tags: android-touch-event

I am building an app that needs to get screen cooordinates for any part clicked, both inside and outside my app.Also if possible it may give information about how many pointers are involved in the touch event.My device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that I dont even need to do that. I can simply take a screenshot and get pixel colors from it.